# Typescript - Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects - How to use constants in place of strings in hookrouter's route?

Tags: string, typescript, react-hooks, constants

```
import React from "react";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import About from "./components/About";
const routes = {
  "/": () => <Users />,
  "/about": () => <About />,
  "/contact": () => <Contact />
};
export default routes;
```

May I know how to use constants instead of strings in the routes as follows please?

```
const root = "/";

const routes = {
  `${root}`: () => <Users />,
};
```

When I tried the code above, I got the following error:

```
Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects
```

Comment: What if you put parentheses around the JSX?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you let me know where exactly please?

Comment: Exactly "around the JSX", `() => (<Users />),`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ```${root}`: () => (<Users />),``` Still I get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The syntax for a *computed property name*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ComputedPropertyName) in an object literal is `[someExpression]`, not `` `${someExpression}` ``:

```js
const root = "/";

const routes = {
  [root]: () => <Users />,
};
```

[[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&esModuleInterop=false&target=99&jsx=1&ts=4.0.0-dev.20200612#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqhApgJwgLhgQzATxgXhgG8BfAbgCgLRJZkQRZCAiAemcuvGhnoFcoiCAWIUYMANr1GAXQwAKAJQEAfDAA8CFMNYqANBXIUgA)]

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue when I was using an arrow function by returning a key value pair object , below is the code when issue occurred

```js
const methodTest = (value) => { key1 : value,key2:value };
```

The solution is to add a `()` around the braces `{}` . Below is the solution for the above issue

```js
const methodTest = (value) => ({key1:value , key2:value });
```

The fix is to [wrap the object literal in parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:%7E:text=To%20fix%20this%2C%20wrap%20the%20object%20literal%20in%20parentheses%3A)