# How do I resolve the "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)" error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import React from "react";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { Industry, industryState } from "../atoms/industriesAtoms";

const useIndustryData = () => {
  const [industryStateValue, setIndustryStateValue] =
  useRecoilState(industryState);

  const onJoinOrLeaveIndustry = (industryData: Industry, isJoined: boolean) => {
    // is the user signed in
    // if not => open auth modal

    if (isJoined) {
      leaveIndustry(industryData.id);
      return;
    }
    joinIndustry(industryData);
    // onJoinOrLeaveIndustry;
  };

  const joinIndustry = (industryData: Industry) => {};

  const leaveIndustry = (industryId: string) => {};

  return (

  // data and functions,
  *industryStateValue,* onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
 );

};
export default useIndustryData;
```

I am working on the code above in a react project and I'm getting an error that Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695) in line 27 of the screenshot.

I want to understand why I am getting this error, and how I can resolve it.

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356722/typescript-left-side-of-comma-operator-is-unused-and-has-no-side-effects-how), but the solution wasn't helpful in my own case.[image: Left side of comma operator is unused ...]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code:

```
return (
    // data and functions,
    industryStateValue, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
return (
    // data and functions,
    onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
);
```

...since `industryStateValue` is a simple variable, so evaluating it has no side-effects. The [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates its left-hand operand, throws that value away, evaluates its right-hand operand, and then takes that value as its result.

If you meant to return both of those values, you have to wrap them in something. When it's just two or three like that, it's common to wrap them in an array:

```
return [ // <===
    // data and functions,
    industryStateValue, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
];       // <===
```

Then the code using the hooks can destructure into discrete variables, just like you do with `useState` or `useRecoilState`:

```
const [state, handler] = useIndustryData();
```

You can use an object instead of an array if you like, by using `{}` instead of `[]`:

```
return { // <===
    // data and functions,
    industryStateValue, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
};       // <===
```

Then the code using it would use object destructuring (`{}` instead of `[]`):

```
const { industryStateValue, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry } = useIndustryData();
```

For small numbers of values (say, three or fewer), the usual thing is to use an array like [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and [`useRecoilState`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilState) do, because it's easier for the caller to control the names of the variable they destructure into. But for four or more values, an object is clearer because when you get into that many, positional destructuring can be hard to follow. Here's how a caller would use different names (`state` and `handler` as in the array examples) when destructuring an object:

```
const { industryStateValue: state, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry: handler } = useIndustryData();
```

Comment: This worked 

```return [ // <===
    // data and functions,
   industryStateValue, onJoinOrLeaveIndustry
]; ```

I found out I could also use curly brace "{}" in place of the '[]'. I guess the difference would be that I am returning an object instead of an array.

Many thanks.

Comment: @InnocentOyebode - Yup. :-) Normally you'd use an array for a small number of values, not an object (again, like `useStae` or `useRecoilState` do), because it's more convenient to use, since you can easily and concisely control the names of the variables you destructure into. But you *can* return a non-array object instead if you want. That's usually best if there are more than three things being returned and so positional destructuring gets a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by accidentally naming a new file `.ts`, instead of `.tsx`.

The file had JSX in it, and was causing issues with the linter (eslint) not recognizing the JSX as valid inside a JS Object.

Once I changed the file extension to `.tsx`, the linter calmed down, and recognized the object structure as valid. :)

Here is a simple example to show what was triggering the error in my case:

```
const getMenuItems = () => {
  return [
    {
      type: 'link',
      title: 'List',
      link: '/agents/list',
      icon: {
        asset: <NavIcon icon={'rocket'} />,
      },
    },
  ];
```

Since the property `asset` contains JSX, the linter was throwing a fit when the file extension was `.ts`. With `.tsx`, everything was fine.

This, of course, is expected behavior, but it took me a minute to realize what was going on--especially since the error I was getting didn't really help pin-point the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a little dangling comma hanging off of an element in a React short circuit evaluation.

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {condition && (
        <p>Hello World</p>,
      )}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Tough to spot.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was that i meant to have an object literal evalute dynamically, but instead i inadverdently created a block scope and what followed was not valid syntax anymore. i had a similar snippet to the following contrived example:

```js
{
    phone: () => console.log('phone'),
    email: () => console.log('email'),
}[magicField.type]();
```

the solution is to wrap the curly braces with parentheses so they are interpreted as an object literal, if that is your intention:

```js
({
    phone: () => console.log('phone'),
    email: () => console.log('email'),
})[magicField.type]();
```

Answer (score 0):

very tough to spot this subtle error, and it in most cases (to me at least) caused by a dangling comma at the end of the return.

```
  return {
    measure: "",
    value: "",
    perValue: "",
    perUnit: "",
  },
```

you see that comma at the end?? that is the culprit.

because at the end of any statement (be it return or any other) a 'semicolon' is expected (optionally) so we have a comma there that is causing the problem.

So, remove it or replace with a semicolon.

```
  return {
    measure: "",
    value: "",
    perValue: "",
    perUnit: "",
  };
```

TaDa!!